# Same Receiver in several different apps

Tags: android, receiver

I have three different versions of my app. Each version has its own small application project, and all three apps share a common library project which contains the bulk of the code and resources. So, the following packages are involved:

```
com.mycompany.myapp.app1
com.mycompany.myapp.app2
com.mycompany.myapp.app3
com.mycompany.myapp.lib
```

The library project includes a `Receiver` which I use to listen for the `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` intent. The `Receiver` is registered in each of the projects' `AndroidManifest.xml` files with its fully qualified name:

```
<receiver android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.lib.MyBootReceiver">
```

I am now seeing that on reboot, if I have all three versions of the app installed side-by-side, only one of them is having its `Receiver` called. Is this because the `Receiver` is declared with the same name for each app? Should each app have its own separately-named version of the `Receiver` instead?

Comment: If you are testing this on Android 3.1+, make sure you have manually invoked all three applications (e.g., launcher icon) before the reboot. On 3.1+, applications begin in a "stopped" state and will not receive broadcasts until the user runs them once.

Comment: @CommonsWare OK, thanks. This is on 2.2, though.

Comment: Well, so much for that theory...

Comment: graham, did you ever find a solution to this problem? i am encountering a similar problem. i am unable to reproduce the problem on any of my own devices, but some of my users have sent logcat output that shows that the receiver is not working on their phones. a previous version of my app that had the receiver in the same package does work for them, so having the receiver in a package that is different from the app's own package seems to be an issue for some users.

Comment: No solution yet, although I haven't really gone back to look at it since I posted the question.